# express permutations with a fixed element and fixed number of elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I want to express permutations with a fixed element an fixed number of elements. Note that I don't want to actually count them, I need an elegant way to write it down. Here I go:

I have a set $S$ and a special element $e$. I want to express permutations of the form:

$<s_i, e, s_j>$

where $s_i,s_j \in S$ and $e$ is the special element.

That is, my permutations only have 3 elements and $e$ always appears in the middle.

How can I express this?

Comment: What do you mean by "express" here? It looks like you already have a notation for your thing, so "express" apparently doesn't mean "write down" ... Hmm, are you looking for a way to write down the _set of_ all your triples? That would be $S\times \{e\}\times S$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I meant that. Writing it as the cartesian product looks clean and simple

Answer (score 1):

A permutation is formally defined to be a bijection from a set to itself.  In your case with the set $S = <s_i, e, s_j >$ we would say a permutation is a function $\pi : S \rightarrow S$ such that $S$ is one-to-one and onto, i.e.  $\pi(x) = \pi(y) \implies x = y$ and $\forall y \in S \hspace{2mm} \exists x \in S \text{ such that } \pi(x) = y$.  Thus we can describe the set of fixed points in the permutation $S' = \{x \in S : \pi(x) = x \}$.  In your case $e \in S'$. If you want to say that $S$ has a certain number of fixed elements, say $n$, then you could write $|S'| = n$ which means that the set $S'$ has $n$ elements.